# Doors count all inlinks

Tags: ibm-doors

I want to count all inlinks of all objects in all modules in a IBM Doors Project. (with DXL)

So this is how I did it (in main im calling the function `goThroughFolders(current Folder)):`

1. Go through every folder in the project and check if there are modules if there are modules call the function "checkLinks(Module m)"

   ```
       void goThroughFolders(Folder f)
       {
           Item itm
           if (null f) return

           for itm in f do{

                   print("\nScanning folder...")
                   if (null itm) continue
                   if (isDeleted(itm)) continue

                   else if ((type (itm) == "Project") || (type (itm) == "Folder"))
                       {
                     goThroughFolders(folder(itm))
                       }
                   else if (type (itm) == "Formal") {
                       print("\nFound Module")
                       checkLinks(module(itm))
                       }

           }
   }
   ```

   2. Check modules for links

      ```
      void checkLinks(Module m)
      {
          string objType = ""
          Object o = null
          Link anyLink
          for o in m do {

      objType = o."Object Type" ""

      // Check if the type is right
      if ( ( objType == "Req" ) || ( objType == "Obj" ) ) {
          // Check for any outlinks at all
          for anyLink in o <- "*" do{



         LinkCount++

         }
      ```

      }
      }
      }

So my problem is the function call `checkLinks(module(itm))` in `goThroughFolders(Folder f)` seems to hand over a `null` Object.

```
Error:

    -R-E- DXL: <Line:11> null Module do loop parameter was passed
    Backtrace:
        <Line:69> 
        <Line:78> 
    -I- DXL: execution halted
```

But I dont know why? Can you help me?

Comment: Found my mistake in checkLinks() it has to be
                    m = read (fullName(itm), false, true) //open the module
                    checkLinks(m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good job spotting the missing step. One other thing you might want to do is close the modules after you finish the analysis, otherwise, you're likely to forget and leave them open, sacrificing memory, until you exit DOORS.

I've made a few modifications and additions below to achieve this - if anything's unclear, please feel free to ask.

Richard

```
Module m
Skip skLinkSourceMods = create() // Create a skip list to hold references to all modules opened for link analysis

int linkCount = 0

void checkLinks(Item itm, Skip skOpenMods) // Function signature changed to pass in the skip list - not strictly necessary, but clean
{
    m = read (fullName(itm), false, true)
    put(skOpenMods, m, m) // Add the opened module to the skip list, so we can easily close it later
    string objType = ""
    Object o = null
    Link anyLink

    for o in m do {
        objType = o."Object Type" ""

        // Check if the type is right
        if ( ( objType == "Req" ) || ( objType == "Obj" ) ) {

        // Check for any outlinks at all
            for anyLink in o <- "*" do {
               linkCount++
           }
       }
    }
}

void goThroughFolders(Folder f)
{
    Item itm
    if (null f) return

    for itm in f do {
        print("\nScanning folder...")
        if (null itm) continue
        if (isDeleted(itm)) continue

        else if ((type (itm) == "Project") || (type (itm) == "Folder"))
        {
          goThroughFolders(folder(itm))
        }
        else if (type (itm) == "Formal") {
            print("\nFound Module")

            checkLinks(itm, skLinkSourceMods) // Function signature changed (see above) to pass in the skip list - not strictly necessary, but clean
        }
    }
}

void closeModules(Skip skOpenMods)
{
    for m in skOpenMods do // Loop through each module in the skip list
    {
        close(m, false) // Close the module without saving changes (we shouldn't have any - they were opened read-only anyway!)
    }
}

goThroughFolders(current Folder)
print "\n" linkCount " links."
closeModules(skLinkSourceMods)
delete(skLinkSourceMods)
```